# Fragmentstatepageradapter replace fragment

Tags: replace, tabs, android-viewpager, fragmentstatepageradapter

I am using viewpager with tabs. I have 2 tabs and each tabs has a listview. I am using fragmentstatepageradapter like that:

```
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
           return new fragmenttab1();
        case 1:
            return new fragmenttab2();
  }
    return null;
```

I want to replace fragments on current position when click on any Item in listview.. How can I do it?